# View Balance without a transaction hash

Tags: viewkey

Where and how can I check my Monero balance without having a transaction hash?  As a merchant I just need to control whether a client has payed the Monero to my wallet.  I have a paper wallet.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot view amounts, and thus check your balance, with just a transaction hash. Amounts on the Monero blockchain are encrypted.

What you will need to do is take your paper wallet and restore either a full or view-only wallet using the seed words printed on your paper wallet. Then using the restored wallet you can scan the blockchain for incoming payments.

Refer to the guides: [How to make a view-only wallet](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/view_only.html) and [Securely purchasing and storing Monero](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/securely_purchase.html).